# How to create a custom event in rules?

Tags: rules, actions

I need to create an custom event for an action to be triggered in the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module.

Custom event is after completing the checkout process the page will be redirected to confirmation page. I need to trigger an action if the page is redirected to the confirmation page.

I need to check if the user has on the confirmation page like /payment-confirmation then i need to trigger an action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) action that you want to trigger is to just set a Drupal message like "**Rules action related to payment confirmation**". But this action should only be triggered when "Viewing the content" located at your confirmation page, which has a path like "`/payment-confirmation`".

To get this to work, use the rule below (in Rules export format, just import it in your site and check the results of it):

```
{ "rules_extra_action_about_payment_confirmation" : {
    "LABEL" : "Extra action about payment confirmation",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_view" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "site:current-page:path" ], "value" : "/payment-confirmation" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Rules action related to payment confirmation" } } ]
  }
}
```

The rule above should be close to what you're looking for, except from these further refinements:

- Replace the rules ***Action*** by your own rules "action" (which you didn't specify).
- If you want your Rules Action to be performed **before** your confirmation page is actually shown, then replace the Rules ***Event*** (= `"ON" : { "node_view" : [] },`) with `"ON" : { "init" : [] },` (= "Drupal is initializing").